# VB - Would it be possible to set running timer in a messagebox?

Tags: vb.net

I was able to show the current time and date in a messagebox but would like to do in in real time and would like to ask if its possible with the help of timer1.tick? using label1.text is possible though but i want messagebox to use.

i already tried several methods but with no proper results, its either i received error messages or messagebox keeps popping. I just want the "text" inside the messagebox to change/run realtime, not the messagebox itself, would it be possible?

here's the code i have so far(a private sub sample), with interval = 1000 set, having 2 handle events.

```
Private Sub TimeToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TimeToolStripMenuItem.Click, Timer1.Tick
    MessageBox.Show("Current Time:" & vbCrLf & DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy - hh:mm:ss tt"), "Time", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End Sub
```

any help is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The built-in messagebox does not support that feature but nothing prevents you from building your own messagebox. Have a look at http://emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2006/01/A-custom-MessageBox.aspx

Comment: emoreau at stackOverflow, awesome!